# How to get data into the ViewModel of a UserControl?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, user-controls, viewmodel

New to WPF/MVVM. I have a data object of type "MyData". One of its properties is of type "MySubsetData".

I show a collection of "MyData" objects in a datagrid.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyDataCollection}">
    <!-- Each row of the datagrid contains an item of type "MyData" -->
    <DataGrid.Columns .../>
    <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:MySubsetDataUserControl/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
</DataGrid>
```

The row details should show the content of "MySubsetData". The view of the row details is in a separate user control (here: "MySubsetDataUserControl").

At the moment I don't set a view model for "MySubsetDataUserControl", so it inherits the data context from the parent's datagrid row.

```
<UserControl>
    <!-- Namespace stuff not shown for simplicity -->
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding Path=MySubsetData}">
        <!-- Show the MySubsetData properties here -->
        <!-- e.g. a textbox -->
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=TextData, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Altough this is working I face several problems with this approach:

1. All business logic will be in the user control parent's view model, where it simply doesn't belong. Making the view model messier than it need to be. Not to mention that command bindings in the user controls xaml look very ugly as well. It just doesn't feel right.
2. As more row details could be visible at the same time, I can't bind the properties of "MySubsetData" to an observable property in the view model. I.e. if I change a property in code (e.g. TextData) the change will not be reflected in the view. My workaround is not to alter the property "TextData". Instead I change the content of the textbox Text property, which in turn will update the "TextData" property. And that feels very wrong!

So I would like to use another view model for my user control, but I don't know how to access my data then.

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <local:UserControlViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

How do I access "MySubsetData" now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let assume you have a view model like this:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<MyData> MyDataCollection{get; private set;}
}
```

Where

```
public class MyData
{
    public MySubsetData MySubsetData { get; }
}
```

Your view containing the DataGrid would be

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <local:ViewModel>
</UserControl.DataContext>

<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyDataCollection}">
    <DataGrid.Columns .../>
    <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
        <DataTemplate> 
            <!-- each row of the items control has an implicit DataContext of MyData -->
            <!-- so bind the DataContext of the subset control to MySubsetData -->
            <local:MySubsetDataUserControl DataContext={Binding MySubsetData}/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
</DataGrid>
```

Now your subset control can look like

```
<UserControl>
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=TextData, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

On re-reading the question, maybe all I've done is repeat the Xaml from the question in a slightly different way.

However the various classes should be implementing INotifyPropertyChanged, e.g.

```
public class MySubsetData : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   public string TextData
   {
      get{...}
      set{...; OnPropertyChanged("TextData"); }
   }
}
```

Then the TextBox bound to the TextData property will reflect changes made in code.

Comment: Your answer describes my setup correctly. That's what I am currently doing. You just set the user controls context in the call itself, while I am doing it in the user controls grid. So yours is more elegant, but doesn't answer my question.

Comment: You say 'if I change a property in code (e.g. TextData) the change will not be reflected in the view'.  It will be reflected if the view model implements INotifyPropertyChanged and TextData property raises OnPropertyChanged("TextData").

Comment: That's exactly the point. Let's say I have two row details visible. One row showing "MyData1.MySubsetData.TextData". The other one showing "MyData2.MySubsetData.TextData". So the data grids view model can't have a single observable TextData property. Or where is my mistake here?

Comment: Ok. Just read your edited answer. So the data container is the problem. Interesting. Never thought about that. Might need to write a wrapper class around it. That will take some time. So a separate view model for a user control is not feasible?

Comment: If the user control has its own view model, then you would need to add dependency properties to the control.  You would bind to those properties and the dp event handlers would update the view model.  A bit convoluted though.